# 13920 TypeError in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and getting the following error

> **angular.js:13920TypeError**: CRUDService.ShoppingList_InsertUpdate is not a function

Below is my  **Controller**

```
app.controller('addShopItem', ['$scope', '$http', 'CRUDService', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, CRUDService, uiGridConstants) {
    var apiRoutePost = 'http://localhost:vvvvv/api/ShoppingListAPI/Post/';

    $scope.addShoppingItem = function () {
        CRUDService.ShoppingList_InsertUpdate(apiRoutePost, $scope.ShoppingList);
    };

}]);
```

and my CRUDService javascript

```
app.service('CRUDService', function ($http) {
    //**********----Get Shopping List Items----***************
    $scope.getShoppingListItems = function (apiRoute) {
        return $http.get(apiRoute);
    }

    //**********----Insert Shopping List Items----***************
    $scope.ShoppingItems.InsertUpdate = function (apiRoutePost, data) {
        return $http.post(apiRoutePost, data);
    }

});
```

Appreciate help

Comment: Have a look on the correct way of building `services` - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services. The purpose of a Scope is to "glue together" the presentation and the business logic of your app. It does not make much sense to pass a $scope into a service. Avoid using `$scope` on `service` level.

Comment: I don't think you are creating your service correctly. Where does $scope come from? It's been a while since I wrote one but take a look at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong way. You don't use scope in Service, you bind your all function to **Service** and later can access in **Controller** by using `ServiceName.functionName`. There are different ways to bind function to Service

1.Binding to service directly

```
this.ShoppingList_InsertUpdate = function (apiRoutePost, data) {
        return $http.post(apiRoutePost, data);
    }
```

2. Writing simple functions and bind them latter with this way

```
function ShoppingList_InsertUpdate(apiRoutePost, data){
 return $http.post(apiRoutePost, data);
}
this.ShoppingList_InsertUpdate = ShoppingList_InsertUpdate;
```

and in controller

```
 CRUDService.ShoppingList_InsertUpdate(apiRoutePost, $scope.ShoppingList);
```

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
app.controller('addShopItem', ['$scope', '$http', 'CRUDService', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, CRUDService, uiGridConstants) {
var apiRoutePost = 'http://localhost:vvvvv/api/ShoppingListAPI/Post/';

$scope.addShoppingItem = function () {
    CRUDService.ShoppingList.InsertUpdate(apiRoutePost, $scope.ShoppingList);

};

}]);
```

Service

```
app.service('CRUDService', function ($http) {
this.shoppinListItem = {};
this.getShoppingListItems = {};
//**********----Get Shopping List Items----***************
this.getShoppingListItems = function (apiRoute) {
    return $http.get(apiRoute);
}

//**********----Insert Shopping List Items----***************
this.ShoppingItems.InsertUpdate = function (apiRoutePost, data) {
    return $http.post(apiRoutePost, data);
}
```

});